# How to implement Tap To Focus in Flutter Camera Plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

A very simple question: how to implement tap to focus functionality for the Flutter camera plugin?

I’ve searched the entire World Wide Web about solutions, but I found nothing.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the camera controller method to set the focus manually :

```
controller.setFocusPoint(offset)
```

See the official Api documention [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraController/setFocusPoint.html) for learn about method and camera functions.

The method need a point to focus. The x,y point have to be > 0 and < 1 where 0 is top left point of the camera and 1 the bottom right.

Then you have to retrieve your camera size and create proportions.

Here is a full sample code that you can copy and run

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: CameraApp()));
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  late CameraController controller;
  bool showFocusCircle = false;
  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return  GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: (details) {
        _onTap(details);
      },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
                child: CameraPreview(controller)
            ),
            if(showFocusCircle) Positioned(
                top: y-20,
                left: x-20,
                child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white,width: 1.5)
              ),
            ))
          ],
        )
    );
  }


  Future<void> _onTap(TapUpDetails details) async {
    if(controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showFocusCircle = true;
      x = details.localPosition.dx;
      y = details.localPosition.dy;

      double fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      double cameraHeight = fullWidth * controller.value.aspectRatio;

      double xp = x / fullWidth;
      double yp = y / cameraHeight;

      Offset point = Offset(xp,yp);
      print("point : $point");

      // Manually focus
      await controller.setFocusPoint(point);
      
      // Manually set light exposure
      //controller.setExposurePoint(point);
      
      setState(() {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).whenComplete(() {
          setState(() {
            showFocusCircle = false;
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware to add bounds for the x,y point value to avoid crash if the tap is beyond the camera preview :

```
if (point != null &&
      (point.dx < 0 || point.dx > 1 || point.dy < 0 || point.dy > 1)) {
    throw ArgumentError(
        'The values of point should be anywhere between (0,0) and (1,1).');
  }
```

Besides, the focus point is not available for the IOS camera ***front*** as far as I know, so allow the focus tap only on back camera lens.

Comment: unfortunately the circle appears in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever is facing problems with the **focus circle** of the above solution, just make sure that the `Positioned` widget is the **direct child of the `Stack` widget**. I had the same problem and after a few searches found the solution.

You can read the documentation for the [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to know more.

Further, after I used the `Stack` widget, I faced problem with the position of the shutter button in my code. I resolved this by simply using another `Positioned` widget to hold the button.

This is the my code for the current minimal UI. I am planning to add pinch to zoom and other features, so it is kind of incomplete. Anyway, I hope it helps others.

```
class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  late CameraController controller;
  XFile? pictureFile;

  // for tap to focus
  bool showFocusCircle = false;
  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(
      widget.cameras![0],
      ResolutionPreset.max,
    );
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const SizedBox(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: (details) {
        _onTap(details);
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 700,
                width: 700,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
                child: CameraPreview(controller),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 40,
            bottom: 40,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  pictureFile = await controller.takePicture();
          
                  // Preview Picture in another page
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ImagePreview(pictureFile!),
                    ),
                  );
          
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: const Text(' '),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (showFocusCircle)  
            Positioned(
              top: y - 20,
              left: x - 20,
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5)),
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onTap(TapUpDetails details) async {
    if (controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showFocusCircle = true;
      x = details.localPosition.dx;
      y = details.localPosition.dy;

      print(x);
      print(y);

      double fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      double cameraHeight = fullWidth * controller.value.aspectRatio;

      double xp = x / fullWidth;
      double yp = y / cameraHeight;

      Offset point = Offset(xp, yp);
      print("point : $point");

      // Manually focus
      await controller.setFocusPoint(point);

      // Manually set light exposure
      controller.setExposurePoint(point);

      setState(() {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).whenComplete(() {
          setState(() {
            showFocusCircle = false;
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

This is how it looks.

[https://i.imgur.com/shydRWO.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqLue.jpg)